# How to override method of instance

Tags: scala

Is it possible to override some method of an instance of some class.

Something like this

```
class A {
 val x = 1
 def foo() =
  x * 2
}

val a = new A()

//note i cant change class 'A' or creation of 'a'
//also 'A' has like 50 other methods that i dont wish to deal with

//so this does not work but is there some way to do it ?

val b = a extends{

 override def foo() = 
  x * 4

}

b.foo() // desired 4
```

thx

Answer (score 5):

You can new Instance and override inside {} (no need to `extend`)

```
val b = new A {
    override def foo() = x * 4
}
```

Or another idea is creating class A with function as a variable to make it more generic class.

```
class A(f: Int => Int) {
    val x = 1
    def foo() = f(x)
}
```

Comment: Like mentioned in my original question, i cant change class A, also i cant change the creation of the instance i have already an instance a: A, now i need to wrap it (if there is no other solution, guess there is none)

Answer (score 3):

If the `A` definition is not `sealed` (and in a different source file) then you can create a "wrapper" for it.

```
class B(a:A) extends A {
  override def foo() = x * 4
  // use the a:A to extract/mirror instance data (if any)
}

val a = new A
val b = new B(a)
b.x      // res1: Int = 1  <-- acts like an A
b.foo()  // res2: Int = 4  <-- except for what's been overridden
```

Comment: Hi, thx i was aware of this solution (which is correct) but i would have to override 50 methods like override def xx = a.xx, i was hoping to deal with only the one method. Its maybe impossible to do that without reflection :/

Comment: Why would you "have to override 50 methods"? If you "don't wish to deal with" them then don't. If `A` has `foo()`, `bar()`, and `baz()`, and you only want `foo()` to change, then there's no reason to override `bar()` and `baz()`. If you really **do** need to override all methods then that's a different question then the one you've asked. If you have to change all methods then what exactly is the relationship between `a` and `b`?

Comment: What if the object could be of any of several classes like A, B, C.. etc which need to be extended at runtime. All the classes A,B,C.. extends from a common parent base-class.

Comment: @RemisHaroon-رامز; Please post this as a new question, where you'll have more room to demonstrate your issues by posting complete code examples.

Comment: Calling `baz()` on `b` will call the base class `A.baz()` and not the `a:A` instance of `baz()`. Thus, `B` would need an override for every single method of `A` where each implementation would need to proxy `a:A`.